# Conversion lambert to WGS84 (Geocoding + Oracle Locator)

Tags: oracle, geocoding, spatial

I'm currently tying to geocode addresses in Austria. From a given postal code and street etc. I want to automatically find latitude and longitude in WGS84 format. My first approach was to use a webservice like OpenStreetMaps Nominatim. Actually this gives decent results.

Still it is *mandatory* to use a disk with addresses (PAC) and their respective geolocation as a ground truth. Only if I'm not able to match the address within this data I can use the web service approach as a backup solution.

So much for context, now the problem:
On this disk the gelocation is given as X_LAMBERT and Y_LAMBERT and I can't quite figure out how to convert into latitude+longitude.

The diks's data is loaded into an Oracle 11g database with Locator and I'm doing the following:

Step 1:
Creation of spatial geometry object: `MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003,31287,NULL, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(X_LAMBERT,Y_LAMBERT))`

Step 2: Projection from WGS84 to LatLng:
`SDO_CS.TRANSFORM( GEOMETRY, 4326)` in my Java client I obtain latitude, longitude from the geometry via `oracle.spatial.geometry.JGeometry`.

Note:
I suspect 31287 to be SRID of the lambert format, I tried 8307 and 3416, but latter give even worse results.Step 2 works fine with other geometry objects, where I know the correct SRID for sure... so I guess the error is somewhere in Step 1.

Do I have to set something in `USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA` ? Wrong usage of `SDO_GEOMETRY` constructor ? Am I still mixing up datum and projection? Maybe you can enlighten me there aswell...

The result of my action and example for input are:

`Input: X_LAMBERT 602823, Y_LAMBERT 464397
Resulting Output: WGS84 (48.0469757028535, 16.0542604612583)
Expected Output: WGS84 (48.546363, 16.085735)`

Its like almost correct, but still some 100 kilometers off ;-)

Comment: Are you shure you use the correct datum and projection for your coordinates? EPSG codes for Austria you you find here: [Übersicht über EPSG Codes für Österreich](http://www.bev.gv.at/pls/portal/docs/PAGE/BEV_PORTAL_CONTENT_ALLGEMEIN/0100_NEWS/0150_ARCHIV/ARCHIV_2007/NEUE%20EPSG%20-%20CODES%20FUER%20OESTERREICH/PROJEKTIONEN_TRANSF.PDF). A very reliable open-source converter is this one: [Proj.4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj). It is available for various plattforms and has been ported to many other progamming languages.

Comment: No, I'm not sure. I tried almost all of the ones in the list you provided :/ 31287 yields best results, all the others are somewhere in Czech or Bulgaria :D

Comment: How do I use Proj4? `cs2cs.exe +init=epsg:31287 +to +epsg:4326` is apparently not correct syntax...

Comment: It is this: `cs2cs +init=epsg:31287 +to +init=epsg:4326` or `cs2cs -f "%.9f" +init=epsg:31287 +to +init=epsg:4326` for decimal output.

Comment: Maybe for correct transformation parameters you should better ask at this StackExchange page: [Geographic Information Systems](http://gis.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Meanwhile I have a gut feeling that it is probably the EPSG:3416, which is Lambert projection but with another ellipsoid and reference latitude... Because my results are almost 0.5 degrees of. Unfortunately Oracle Locator doesn't know 3416 I have to import the definition somehow.

Comment: You can create your own custom coordinate system in Oracle Spatial if it does not exist, see here: [Creating a User-Defined Coordinate Reference System](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_cs_concepts.htm#i894537)

Comment: Turns out I need "Austrian Lambert 48", http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7064/ With your link to the manual I was able to create it. Thanks, if you provide an answer I can accept it.